# Re-declaring a function in a child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, function

P.S. Hi Admin, I tried looking for the solution but could not see the same issue anywhere!

Hi all,

I have a child theme. I have a function which is wrapped in if !function_exists as below. The file in is includes folder. The function is in wp-content/themes/themename/includes/alias-function.php

```
 if (!function_exists('jem_render_buy_fee ')) {
function jem_render_buy_fee() {
    $fee=(ea_get_option('order_commission_buyer'))?ea_get_option('order_commission_buyer'):'';
    if($fee){
        ?>
        <div class="jem-commission-fee">
            <span><?php _e($fee.'% commission fee included', 'themes'); ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
}
```

Because it is in includes folders but wrapped in function_exists, so I declare the function in functions.php as below. This file is in wp-content/themes/themename-child/functions.php

```
function jem_render_buy_fee() {
    $fee=(ea_get_option('order_commission_buyer'))?ea_get_option('order_commission_buyer'):'';
    if($fee){
        ?>
        <div class="jem-commission-fee">
            <span><?php _e($fee.'% GST inclusive', 'themes'); ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 1873 of file wp-content/themes/themename/includes/alias-function.php. Please fix and try saving again.

Cannot redeclare jem_render_buy_fee() (previously declared in wp-content/themes/themename-child/functions.php:215)
```

Why am I getting this? The error is wrapped in function_exist.

I can see its loading the function.php, but then it should ignore the existing one in the file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which file are you calling first? The one declaring the function if it doesn't exist (first code) or the on declaring it anyhow (second code)?

Comment: Hi dn Fer. The second code gets called first, since its in child theme's function.php. The first code is the existing one that I am trying to override. The first code is wrapped in if function_exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your check for function existence, there's a space behind the function name.
`!function_exists('jem_render_buy_fee ')`

Without this space it should work fine if the order af calling code is correct.

First Call:

```
function jem_render_buy_fee() {
    $fee=(ea_get_option('order_commission_buyer'))?ea_get_option('order_commission_buyer'):'';
    if($fee){
        ?>
        <div class="jem-commission-fee">
            <span><?php _e($fee.'% GST inclusive', 'themes'); ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Then call:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('jem_render_buy_fee')) { //Space removed from 'jem_render_buy_fee '
    function jem_render_buy_fee() {
        $fee=(ea_get_option('order_commission_buyer'))?ea_get_option('order_commission_buyer'):'';
        if ($fee): ?>
            <div class="jem-commission-fee">
                <span><?php _e($fee.'% commission fee included', 'themes'); ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php endif;
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw that but I was hoping that's not the issue, since then I have to edit the main files of the theme and defeats the purpose of child-theme. I am going to change it now and update you back.

Comment: Ouch! That was it! Cannot believe such a simple space caused me so much trouble. Thanks so much dn Fer. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I assumed it was a typo, but it was the only error I've found. Good luck.